# django how to change account info using UserChangeForm

Tags: python, django

I'm making a website using django. I was learning 'How to Let superusers Change Account Info Using Forms' by youtube. But, I have a problem to go edit page.

member_management.html in management app

```
      {% for staff in staff_list %}
        <tr>
            <td><a href="{% url "management:edit_staff" staff.id %}">{{ staff }}</a></td>
            <td>{{ staff.birth }}</td>
            <td>{{ staff.groups.all.0 }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

If I click the {{staff}}, the page url changes 'management/member_management' to 'management/member_management/edit_staff/1' ( 1 is the staff id ). But page doesn't go to edit_staff page, rather redirect memeber_management page(this page).

my urls.py in management app

```
  from django.conf.urls import url, include
  from management import views

   urlpatterns = [
url(r'^member_management/', views.member_management, name='member_management'),
url(r'^member_management/edit_staff/(?P<staff_id>\d+)', views.edit_staff, name="edit_staff"),  
 ]
```

my views.py in management app

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm
from authentication.models import User
from staff.models import Member

def member_management(request):
    staff_list = User.objects.all()
    member_list = Member.objects.all()
    context = {
        'staff_list':staff_list,
        'member_list' : member_list,
    }
    return render(request, 'management/member_management.html', context)

def edit_staff(request, staff_id):
    staff = User.objects.get(id=staff_id)
    print("sdf")

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserChangeForm(request.POST, instance=staff)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('member_management')
    else:
        staff = User.objects.get(id=staff_id)
        form = UserChangeForm(instance=staff)

    context = {
        'form' : form,
    }
    return render(request, 'management/edit_staff.html', context)
```

What's the problem?? Any error doesn't come in my CMD, maybe some route I miss..
Any help will be very helpful to me, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this, just put the **$ (end-of-string match character)** at the end of the first url.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^member_management/$', views.member_management, 
      name='member_management'),
    url(r'^member_management/edit_staff/(?P<staff_id>\d+)', 
      views.edit_staff, name="edit_staff"),  
]
```

> Note that the regular expressions in this example don’t have a $
>   (end-of-string match character) but do include a trailing slash.
>   Whenever Django encounters include() (django.conf.urls.include()), it
>   chops off whatever part of the URL matched up to that point and sends
>   the remaining string to the included URLconf for further processing.

If you doens't put the $, you may experience unexpected results, something like:

management/member_management/edit_staff/1/foo/bar/baz will match, and will call **views.edit_staff**

To avoid this, you should include the **$** on the edit_staff url too.

```
url(r'^member_management/edit_staff/(?P<staff_id>\d+)$', 
      views.edit_staff, name="edit_staff"),
```